# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@27dfe089 to flash.display.MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

here it is the error >> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@261b4089 to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at com.ply::Heli/fireBullet()
    at com.ply::Heli/myOnPress()

this is Heli's Class :

```
package com.ply 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import com.peluru.Bullet;

public class Heli extends MovieClip
{
    var shotCooldown:int;
    const MAX_COOLDOWN = 10;
    //Settings
    public var xAcceleration:Number = 0;
    public var yAcceleration:Number = 0;
    private var xSpeed:Number = 0;
    private var ySpeed:Number = 0;

    private var up:Boolean = false;
    private var down:Boolean = false;
    private var left:Boolean = false;
    private var right:Boolean = false;

    public function Heli()
    {
        shotCooldown = MAX_COOLDOWN;
        bullets = new Array();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        init();
    }

    public function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myOnPress);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, myOnRelease);
        init();
    }


    private function init():void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, RunHeli);           
    }

    private function RunHeli(event:Event):void
    {
        xSpeed += xAcceleration ;       //increase the speed by the acceleration
        ySpeed += yAcceleration ;       //increase the speed by the acceleration

        xSpeed *= 0.95;                 //apply friction
        ySpeed *= 0.95;                 //so the speed lowers after time

        if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.02)     //if the speed is really low
        {
            xSpeed = 0;                 //set it to 0
                                //Otherwise I'd go very small but never really 0
        }
        if(Math.abs(ySpeed) < 0.02)     //same for the y speed
        {
            ySpeed = 0;
        }

        xSpeed = Math.max(Math.min(xSpeed, 10), -10);       //dont let the speed get bigger as 10
        ySpeed = Math.max(Math.min(ySpeed, 10), -10);       //and dont let it get lower than -10

        this.x += xSpeed;               //increase the position by the speed
        this.y += ySpeed;               //idem

    }

    public function update(e:Event){
    shotCooldown-- ;
    }

    /**
     * Keyboard Handlers
     */
    public function myOnPress(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            xAcceleration  = -1;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            xAcceleration  = 1;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            yAcceleration  = -1;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            yAcceleration  = 1;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            fireBullet();   
        }
    }

    public function myOnRelease(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            xAcceleration  = 0;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            yAcceleration  = 0;
        }

    }       

    public function fireBullet() {
        if (shotCooldown <=0 )
        {
            shotCooldown=MAX_COOLDOWN;
            var b = new Bullet();
            var b2= new Bullet();
            b.x = this.x +20;
            b.y = this.y ;
            b2.x= this.x -20;
            b2.y= this.y ;
            MovieClip(parent).bullets.push(b);
            MovieClip(parent).bullets.push(b2);
            trace(bullets.length);
            parent.addChild(b);
            parent.addChild(b2);
        }
    }

}
```

}

and this is the Main Class

```
package  
{
import com.ply.Heli;
import com.peluru.Bullet;
import com.musuh.Airplane2;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public static const STATE_INIT:int = 10;
    public static const STATE_START_PLAYER:int = 20;
    public static const STATE_PLAY_GAME:int = 30;
    public static const STATE_REMOVE_PLAYER:int = 40;
    public static const STATE_END_GAME:int = 50;        
    public var gameState:int = 0;
    public var player:Heli;
    public var enemy:Airplane2;
    //public var bulletholder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    //================================================
    public var cTime:int = 1;
    //the time it has to reach in order to be allowed to shoot (in frames)
    public var cLimit:int = 10;
    //whether or not the user is allowed to shoot
    public var shootAllow:Boolean = true;
    //how much time before another enemy is made
    public var enemyTime:int = 0;
    //how much time needed to make an enemy
    //it should be more than the shooting rate
    //or else killing all of the enemies would
    //be impossible :O
    public var enemyLimit:int = 64;
    //the player's score
    public var score:int = 0;
    public var gameOver:Boolean = false;
    public var bulletContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    //================================================
    private var nextPlane:Timer;
    public var enemies:Array;
    public var bullets:Array;

    public function Main() 
    {
        gameState = STATE_INIT;
        gameLoop();
    }


    public function gameLoop(): void {
        switch(gameState) {
            case STATE_INIT :
                initGame();
                break
            case STATE_START_PLAYER:
                startPlayer();
                break;  
            case STATE_PLAY_GAME:
                 playGame();
                break;
            case STATE_REMOVE_PLAYER:
                //removePlayer();
                break;      
            case STATE_END_GAME:                    
                break;  

        }

    }       

    public function initGame() :void {
        enemies = new Array();
        bullets = ne Array();

        setNextPlane();

        gameState = STATE_START_PLAYER;
        gameLoop();
        //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, AddEnemy);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, back);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkForHits);
    }

    public function setNextPlane() {
        nextPlane = new Timer(1000+Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextPlane.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newPlane);
        nextPlane.start();
    }


    public function newPlane(event:TimerEvent) {
        // random side, speed and altitude

        // create plane
        var enemy:Airplane2 = new Airplane2();
        enemy.y = -1 * enemy.height;
        //making the enemy's x coordinates random
        //the "int" function will act the same as Math.floor but a bit faster
        enemy.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - enemy.width));
        //then add the enemy to stage
        addChild(enemy);
        enemies.push(enemy);

        // set time for next plane
        setNextPlane();
    }

    public function removePlane(plane:Airplane2) {
        for(var i in enemies) {
            if (enemies[i] == plane) {
                enemies.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // take a bullet from the array
    public function removeBullet(bullet:Bullet) {
        for(var i in bullets) {
            if (bullets[i] == bullet) {
                bullets.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function checkForHits(event:Event) {
        for(var bulletNum:int=bullets.length-1;bulletNum>=0;bulletNum--){ 
            for (var airplaneNum:int=enemies.length-1;airplaneNum>=0;airplaneNum--) {
                if (bullets[bulletNum].hitTestObject(enemies[airplaneNum])) {
                    enemies[airplaneNum].planeHit();
                    bullets[bulletNum].deleteBullet();
                    trace("kena");
                    //shotsHit++;
                    //showGameScore();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //if ((shotsLeft == 0) && (bullets.length == 0)) {
        //  endGame();
        //}
    }


    public function back( evt:Event ):void
    {   // Backgroud Land
        if (Dessert2.y >= 0 && Dessert.y >= 720)
        {
            Dessert.y = Dessert2.y - 1240 ;
        }
        else if (Dessert.y >= 0 && Dessert2.y >= 720)
        {
            Dessert2.y = Dessert.y - 1240 ;
        }
        else 
        {
        Dessert.y = Dessert.y +5 ;
        Dessert2.y = Dessert2.y +5 ;
        }
        // Background Clouds
        if (Clouds2.y >= 0 && Clouds.y >= 720)
        {
            Clouds.y = Clouds2.y - 2480 ;
        }
        else if (Clouds.y >= 0 && Clouds2.y >= 720)
        {
            Clouds2.y = Clouds.y - 2480 ;
        }
        else 
        {
        Clouds.y = Clouds.y +10 ;
        Clouds2.y = Clouds2.y +10 ;
        }
    }

    public function startPlayer() : void { 
        player=new Heli();
        player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        // add Player to display list
        stage.addChild(player);
        gameState = STATE_PLAY_GAME;

    }

    public function playGame():void {

        gameLoop();

        //txtScore.text = 'Score: '+score;


    }

    function AddEnemy(event:Event){
    if(enemyTime < enemyLimit){
        enemyTime ++;
    }   else {
        //defining a variable which will hold the new enemy
        enemy =new Airplane2();
        //making the enemy offstage when it is created
        enemy.y = -1 * enemy.height;
        //making the enemy's x coordinates random
        //the "int" function will act the same as Math.floor but a bit faster
        enemy.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - enemy.width));
        //then add the enemy to stage
        addChild(enemy);
        //and reset the enemyTime
        enemyTime = 0;

     }



        if(cTime <= cLimit){
            cTime ++;
        } else {
        //if it has, then allow the user to shoot
        shootAllow = true;
        //and reset cTime
        cTime = 1;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Use of only one `ENTER_FRAME` event is a good pactice. Use ON/OFF like switch for objects in a single `ENTER_FRAME' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your `player` in Main into `stage` instead of `this` - why, by the way? So, there are two methods of fixing this: First, change line where you add `player` to display list, and second, remove direct coercion from `Heli.fireBullet()` function. I'd say use the first one.

```
public function startPlayer() : void { 
    player=new Heli();
    player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    // add Player to display list
    this.addChild(player); // <-- this, not stage
    gameState = STATE_PLAY_GAME;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
MovieClip(parent).bullets.push(b);
MovieClip(parent).bullets.push(b2);
```

to

```
MovieClip(root).bullets.push(b);
MovieClip(root).bullets.push(b2);
```

Comment: I'd advise against relying on `root` at all, this is IIRC a deprecated property.